# Using WGET to run a cronjob PHP disable notification email

Tags: linux, cron

Im using godaddy as a webhost and id like to disable the email notification that is sent after a cronjob is done. Lucky for me they have been no help but the cronjob area says:

> You can have cron send an email every time it runs a command. If you do not want an email to be sent for an individual cron job you can redirect the command’s output to /dev/null like this: `mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1`

Ive tried several variations of this and nothing seems to fix it.

My command:

```
wget http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=post-by-email&tab=log&check_mail=1
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What combinations you've tried? The suggestion seems right.

Comment: tried: wget http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=post-by-email&tab=log&check_mail=1 >/dev/null 2>&1 
wget http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=post-by-email&tab=log&check_mail=1 >>/dev/null 2>&1 
wget /dev/null http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=post-by-email&tab=log&check_mail=1

Comment: ...I was under the impression that wp-admin scripts needed authentication. Are you sure you don't want to access `wp-mail` instead of `tools`?

Answer (score 7):

As the cronjob area says, you need to redirect the command’s output to **/dev/null**.

**Your command should look like this:**

```
wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null "http://example.com/wp-admin/wp-mail.php" &> /dev/null
```

- The `-O` option makes sure that the fetched content is sent to **/dev/null**.

If you want the fetched content to be downloaded in the server filesystem, you can use this option to specify the path to the desired file.

- The `-o` option logs to **/dev/null** instead of **stderr**
- `&> /dev/null` is another way yo redirect stdout output to **/dev/null**.

**NOTES**

For more information on **wget**, check the **man** pages: you can type `man wget` on the console, or use the online man pages: http://man.he.net/?topic=wget&section=all

With both `-O` and `-o` pointing to **/dev/null**, the output redirection ( &> ... ) should not be needed.

If you don't need to download the contents, and only need the server to process the request, you can simply use the `--spider` argument

Comment: I believe this worked, emails have stopped but trying to test the wget script now to see if its still working. Thanks for the quick replies. I will respond again after I can confirm the script is working. thx

Comment: Appears I have stopped the email but now the wget donesnt work.

Comment: Same seems with the command given the job doesn't work. Here is exactly what I have entered as of now.            wget -O - "http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=post-by-email&tab=log&check_mail=1" >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I see the above code has been edited, trying it now.

Comment: No email sent but the wget doesn't seem to work now, code is as follows: wget -0 /dev/null -o /dev/null "http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=post-by-email&tab=log&check_mail=1" &> /dev/null

Comment: So this is a post by email fetch command that should post blog entries that arrive in a particular inbox. When im saying the command isn't working, the emails are not posting. The semicolon I believe is stackoverflow editing my response and making them smaller I believe.

Comment: Oh, then try triggering the script manually (putting the URL in a browser). If it doesn't work neither this way, then the error is in the script (maybe it needs authentication, or maybe you are running the wrong script. tried using wp-mail?)